# Let Q be orthogonal. Show that Q^tAQ has the same characteristic polynomial. as A.

Tags: matrices

Do I have to use the diagonalization of A?

Comment: No. $I = Q^tQ$, so just use the fact that determinant is multiplicative.

Comment: @BabyDragon The title states that $Q$ is orthogonal...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The characteristic equation is

$$ |Q^TAQ-\lambda I|=0  \iff |Q^T AQ-\lambda Q^TQ |=0 \iff   |Q^T|| AQ-\lambda Q |=0   \\ \iff |Q^T|| A-\lambda I ||Q|=0 \iff | A-\lambda I |=0. $$

since $|Q|=\pm {1}, |Q^T|=\pm {1} $.

Comment: @AVP: You are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

You can also show that the eigenvalues are the same for $A$ and $Q'AQ$.

In one direction, suppose that $v\neq 0$ is such that $Av=\lambda v$. Then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $Q'AQ$ with eigenvector $Q'v$:
$$
[Q'AQ](Q'v)=Q'A[QQ']v=Q'Av=\lambda(Q'v).
$$
Conversely, suppose that $v\neq 0$ is such that $[Q'AQ]v=\lambda v$. Then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with eigenvector $Qv$:
$$
A(Qv)=IAQv=QQ'AQv=Q(Q'AQv)=\lambda(Qv).
$$

Comment: I like this approach also. Thanks a lot.